# Relationship to develop lookup

Tags: database

I have a MS Access DB that has many POCs in several countries with multiple types of phone numbers for each POC.

I need to end up with a report that will allow me to select what type of phone number(s) is/are displayed next to each POC.

Ex.
John Doe Cell: 210-555-1111 Comm: 123-456-8910
Jane Doe Comm: 210-555-1212 
Lil John Bus: 813-245-6789 Cell: 321-879-1119

Instead of having all numbers for all POCs like:
John Doe Cell: # Comm: # Bus: #
Jane Doe Cell: # Comm: # Bus: #
Lil John Cell: # Comm: # Bus: #

Not sure how to go about this.

Thx,
Jason